# Scaleable buttons in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uibutton

I was wondering if its possible, and how i might do the following,

I would like to have a `UIButton`, a simple rounded button with one color, but i would like to have it's width scaleable based upon the `UILabel` that is on the inside of it.

I found somethings that talked about how it's possible to use

`UItextfield`

and use the `.leftView` and `.rightView` properties that it has

Could anyone give me just a quick example of how i might do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the size of the NSString in the UILabel by doing something like this:

`CGSize size=[uibutton.titlelabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:fontSize] forWidth:uibutton.titlelabel.frame.size.width lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap];`

Then set the frame of the uilabel and/or uibutton using this `size.width` and `size.height` properties.

This is just an example, you will need to adjust the UIFont properties based on your label's settings or preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the text of the UILabel will by dynamic, so you cannot just figure out the dimensions and add them normally?

try this:

```
-(void)setLabelText:(NSString*)string
{
   int length = string.length;

   myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 5*length+5, height);
   buttonContainingLabel.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 25+5*length, height);
}
```

This method assumes a monospaced font, which you are probably not using. Still, discrepancies in character width probably won't amount to any meaningful size differential as you are not writing a novel in the button.  I use the value of 5 px here as the width of a letter, but you will have to modify this to fit your text size.